# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS completely freezed

Tags: system

*OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 

Host: Dell Vostro 3520 

Kernel: 6.5.0-25-generic 

Packages: 2050 (dpkg), 17 (snap) 

Shell: bash 5.1.16 

Resolution: 1920x1080 

DE: GNOME 42.9 

WM: Mutter 

WM Theme: Adwaita 

Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 

Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 

Terminal: gnome-terminal 

CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1235U (12) @  

GPU: Intel Device 4628 

Memory: 7617MiB*

Sometimes when I am working it freezes completely, I mean the cursor, the mouse, the screen and the keyboard. If i unplug the charger the sound gets out seconds and seconds late. After some minutes it can unlock by itself just waiting. How could i solve the problem? Just tell me if you need more information about.
I forgot to say that the laptop is brand-new.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: It seems weird because there were just there terminal and Firefox open...

Comment: ctrl+alt+f2 keys for tty

Comment: Open `top` in the terminal to see if any process consumes a lot of RAM. Browser may need a lot of RAM depending on how many tabs are open and how many complex pages are open. However, 8 GB should be sufficient, normally. 
You may also want to run Memtest from the Boot Menu to check whether your RAM may be (partially) damaged. Make sure to run Memtest long enough, not only for a few minutes.